# Where can I see co-op standings in F1 2013?

Tags: f1-2012

Is it possible, during a co-op championship in F1 2013, to see the current standings? F1 2012 showed them (drivers' and constructors') after every race. In F1 2013, instead, if you select "Continue" after a race you are bought directly to the next race. It seems you have to exit the multiplayer session and return to the lobby if you want to know your position. But this sounds very weird. It must be a way.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the left choice (i.e. LB on a Xbox controller) in the "Toggle tables" submenus. Chances are you're selecting the right choice (i.e. RB): doing that you access other infos about the race you've just finished. Yup, it's not that clear.